# Auto login to the site for demo

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, login

Customer will visit the site. once customer click on Login button

it will redirect to the login page .

once customer see the login page, email and password should be there on text field

demo example :

http://magento.webkul.com/Marketplace/index.php/customer/account/login/

customer should only click on login button and it should login to the site.

**Login.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * Customer login form template
 *
 * @see Mage_Customer_Block_Form_Login
 */
?>
<div class="account-login">
    <div class="page-title">
        <h1><?php echo $this->__('Login or Create an Account') ?></h1>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
    <?php /* Extensions placeholder */ ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customer.form.login.extra')?>
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="login-form">
        <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
        <div class="col2-set">
            <div class="col-1 new-users">
                <div class="content">
                    <h2><?php echo $this->__('New Customers') ?></h2>
                    <p><?php echo $this->__('By creating an account with our store, you will be able to move through the checkout process faster, store multiple shipping addresses, view and track your orders in your account and more.') ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 registered-users">
                <div class="content">
                    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Registered Customers') ?></h2>
                    <p><?php echo $this->__('If you have an account with us, please log in.') ?></p>
                    <ul class="form-list">
                        <li>
                            <label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?></label>
                            <div class="input-box">
                                <input type="text" name="login[username]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getUsername()) ?>" id="email" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" />
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="pass" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Password') ?></label>
                            <div class="input-box">
                                <input type="password" name="login[password]" class="input-text required-entry validate-password" id="pass" title="<?php echo $this->__('Password') ?>" />
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
                    </ul>
                    <p class="required"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col2-set">
            <div class="col-1 new-users">
                <div class="buttons-set">
                    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Create an Account') ?>" class="button" onclick="window.location='<?php echo $this->getCreateAccountUrl() ?>';"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Create an Account') ?></span></span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 registered-users">
                <div class="buttons-set">
                    <button type="submit" class="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Login') ?>" name="send" id="send2"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Login') ?></span></span></button>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getForgotPasswordUrl() ?>" class="f-left"><?php echo $this->__('Forgot Your Password?') ?></a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var dataForm = new VarienForm('login-form', true);
    //]]>
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: You need change template file login of frontend and backend in Magento

Comment: @PaW you are right. but can you please inform regarding code? what code needs to be modify ?

Comment: In admin login page, you need change  it in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/login.phtml`, and with frontend, it require your theme

Comment: @PaW i need only in frontend. i am trying app/design/frontend/default/theme_name/template/customer/form/login.phtml for frontend. please guide me what code changes i have to do.

Comment: if you want change template file you can change it in `/app/design/frontend/<name_theme>/default/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml`, if in theme not exist this file, you can find it in `base`

Comment: thanks @PaW as in the answer gave by Qaisar Satti , i am trying to create controller action now .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a account with demo email and login with this script.

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
     $email='demo@ymail.com';                       $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
                            $customer->loadByEmail($email);
                            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->loginById($customer->getId());
```

Comment: i added above code in : :app/design/frontend/default/theme_name/template/customer/form/login.phtml"  but still its asking to enter email & pw.

Comment: i changed the valid email id in your answer....

Comment: and the code execution reload the page. it will redirect to you account page

Comment: i added the code in login.phtml. is i have to add in another file ?

Comment: don't add code in login.phtml create controller action and add code there..

Comment: okay, i will try...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support. need your support like this.